# Change of Variables for Hausdorff Measure

Tags: integration, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, fractal-analysis, hausdorff-measure

(Read bounty text for answering question)

Let $H^{m}$ be the $m$-dimensional Hausdorff measure. Let $D$ be a linear transformation matrix. Consider the change of measure formula:
$$
  \int\limits_{A} f(Dx) \; dH^{m}(x) = \int\limits_{ D A} f(y) \; dD_{*}H^{m}(y)
$$
where $D_{*}H^{m}(M) = H^{m}(D^{-1}M)$ is the pushforward of the Hausdorff measure. Is it possible to find such a function $a(x)$ that
$$
   \int\limits_{ D A} f(y) \; dD_{*}H^{m}(y) = \int\limits_{ D A} f(y) a(y) \; dH^{m}(y)
$$

What if we have a self similar object?

$$A= D_1(A) \cup D_2(A)$$

And transform $D_1(A) \rightarrow A$?

Comment: What do you get when $k=2, m=1$?

Comment: I've commadiered your question for a bounty, hope you don't mind :)

Comment: The symbol $k$ was lost in an edit.  $k$ was the dimension of the space where the linear transformation $D$ is defined.  So my idea of 2012 was: first do the case of arc-length in the plane.

Answer (score 4):

Some remarks.  The original question:

> Does a function $a(y)$ exist?

is (by the Radon-Nikodym theorem) equivalent to the question

> Is the image measure $D_*H^m$ absolutely continuous with respect to $H^m$?

(Let's suppose $A$ has sigma-finite measure.)  And the answer is *yes* if $D$ is a non-singular matrix; the answer is sometimes *no* if $D$ is a singular matrix.  But even knowing function $a(y)$ exists doesn't satisfy Zach, who wants an explicit formula.

**Example** (for the singular case)

Consider the [Cantor singular function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function)
[image: picture]
Our set $A$ is the graph of the function.  It is a set with arc length exactly $2$ (that is, $1$-dimensional Hausdorff measure exactly $2$.)

Take $D$ to be the projection onto the $x$-axis.   What is the image measure $D_*H^1$?  Images of all the horizontal line-segments give us exactly Lebesgue measure in the real line.  But images of the rest (a set of $H^1$-measure $1$) give us a singular measure concentrated on the Cantor set.  The image measure is not absolutely continuous.

Or, alternatively, take $D$ to be the projection onto the $y$-axis.  Now the line segments map to countably many point-masses (total mass $1$), while the rest of the graph maps exactly onto Lebesgue measure on the $y$-axis.  But again, the image measure is not absolutely continuous.

There is a general theorem (due to Besicovitch) that generalizes this example.  A set $E$ in Euclidean space with $0 < H^1(E) < \infty$ may be written as a disjoint union of two parts: one part is (up to measure zero) a countable union of rectifiable curves, the other part is "curve-free" and "dust-like".  (See K. J. Falconer, *Fractal Geometry*, 3rd edition, section 5.2: "Structure of $1$-sets")

**Remark** (non-singular case:   $D_*H^m \ll H^m$)

Suppose the matrix is non-singular.  Then we have inequalities of the form
$$
\alpha \; \text{diam}\; A \le
\text{diam}\; D(A) \le
\beta \; \text{diam}\; A
$$
for all sets $A$.  Here $\alpha, \beta$ are the smallest and largest [singular values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) of $D$, and they are positive because $D$ is nonsingular.

Using that inequality we get
$$
\alpha^m H^m(A) \le H^m(D(A)) \le \beta^m H^m(A),
\\
\alpha^m H^m(D^{-1}(A)) \le H^m(A) \le \beta^m H^m(D^{-1}(A)),
$$
so $D_*H^m \ll H^m$ as claimed.

Comment: Sorry if my edit came off a bit demanding. This is a great start! :)